# Why does the live amd-64 kali linux boot not work (mac user)?

Tags: linux, boot, mac, usb

I followed the steps on the website: https://docs.kali.org/downloading/kali-linux-live-usb-install for the mac usb live boot except for a few. Instead of running the command: **diskutil unmount /dev/disk6** I did **diskutil unmountDisk /dev/disk6** because unmount disk unmounts all volumes including partitions so the unmount by itself would not work. That is an error I found in the tutorial.

Before, I did the usb disk by itself which looked something like this: **disk2s1** and kali linux didn't even show up after rebooting the mac and holding down option.

it works all the way up until I am about to use the actual live amd-64 boot. The gif on this website https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/257365/cannot-start-kali-in-live-mode is the issue that I have and I am trying to find the solution.

So, the question is: How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser. Thank you for sharing your thoughts. However, I don't see any question in there, so I'm going to downvote as this is a QA website. Please review the Help Center on how to ask a good question.

Comment: ok well if you can see my error can you please help me

Comment: Well, it seems you have created the bootable USB stick, but your Mac doesn't want to boot from it. So I think the appropriate question would be to ask "Why doesn't my Mac boot from a bootable USB stick?". Also, if you look at your question, it's a huge mess. Add some whitespace, remove redundant and unnecessary information and add necessary information (what have you tried, what specifically didn't work, what is specifically your question). People don't want to spend 5 minutes analyzing a huge block of text. Make it easy for people to see what the question is and they can answer straight away.

Comment: I tried my best to make it better

Comment: When sitting at the boot picker, does hitting Cmd-Opt-Shift-.    (period) all at once make the drive show up?

Comment: Also, does the disk use GPT or is just MBR?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hold down option when starting the mac . .wait . .two icons will be shown mac hd and efi .use arrow key to select efi press enter .

Comment: No it doesn't two icons show up: mac hd, and windows (mac detects kali linux as windows).

Comment: Mac detects GRUB as windows